# Copy Range Object from one Workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I try to copy a range from a workbook (opened with vba-excel) to another (thisworkbook)

```
Public wbKA as workbook
Sub A()
Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
KAPath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\Data.xlsx"
Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
Set wbKA = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(KAPath)
...
End Sub
```

with this code:

```
Sub Get()
Dim LastRow As Long
    With wbKA.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 1)).Copy
        .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 1)).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetB").Range("A6")
```

The line `.Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 1)).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetB").Range("A6")` is highlighted (yellow) by the debugger with the error that the `copy method could not be applyed to the range object`. The first copy method (just insered by me to check if the error occurs without the Destination part) runs through. I copied the code to another workbook where I apply the copy-destination copy pattern to only one workbook and it is working. Could anyone tell me, why this is not working? The wbKA workbook opens up fine and I can actually perform all I need (Search, Pasting Values into arrays and so on), just the Copy thing doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working from Excel, you do not need to open a new instance. That is creating the copy issues. Try this (Untested)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim thisWb As Workbook, thatWb As Workbook
    Dim thisWs As Worksheet, thatWs As Worksheet
    Dim KAPath As String
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set thisWb = ThisWorkbook
    Set thisWs = thisWb.Sheets("SheetB")

    KAPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Data.xlsx"

    Set thatWb = Workbooks.Open(KAPath)
    Set thatWs = thatWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With thatWs
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 1)).Copy thisWs.Range("A6")
    End With
End Sub
```

**Followup from comments.**

You cannot use `rng.copy Dest.rng` when working with different Excel instances. You will have to first copy it and then paste in the next line. See these examples

**This will not work**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim xl As New Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    xl.Visible = True
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    ws.Range("A1").Value = "Sid"

    ws.Range("A1").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
End Sub
```

**This will work**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim xl As New Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    xl.Visible = True
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    ws.Range("A1").Value = "Sid"

    ws.Range("A1").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues
End Sub
```

Comment: hi! Thanks for your answer, this works fine. Interesting to know that copying my way (even though i dont know why) is not working in this enviroment.

Comment: It's because you can't use that statement while working in different excel instances. Updating my answer.